# reduceByKey in spark for adding tuples

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider an Rdd with below dataset 
where 10000241 is the key and remaining are values

```
 ('10000241',([0,0,1],[None,None,'RX']))
 ('10000241',([0,2,0],[None,'RX','RX']))
 ('10000241',([3,0,0],['RX',None,None]))


pv1 = rdd.reduceBykey(lambda x,y :(
                   addtup(x[0],y[0]),
                   addtup(x[1],y[1]),
                ))


def addtup(t1,t2):
    j =()
    for k,v in enumerate(t1):
        j = j + (t1[k] + t2[k],)
     return j
```

The final output i want is (10000241,(3,2,1)('RX','RX','RX)) 
but i get the error of cant add none type to none type or nonetype to Str .how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is a Spark problem, but given those three elements in standard Python, how would you combine the RX string with None? That's the error

Comment: Also what you're trying to do reminds me of the COALESCE operator in SQL, except you've got 0 and None instead of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to summarize numbers in the first tuple and to use logic or in the second?

I think you should rewrite your function as following:

```
def addtup(t1,t2):
  left = list(map(lambda x: sum(x), zip(t1[0], t2[0])))
  right = list(map(lambda x: x[0] or x[1], zip(t1[1], t2[1])))
  return (left, right)
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
rdd.reduceBykey(addtup)
```

Here is a demonstration

```
import functools

data = (([0,0,1],[None,None,'RX']), 
 ([0,2,0],[None,'RX','RX']),
 ([3,0,0],['RX',None,None]))


functools.reduce(addtup, data)
#=> ([3, 2, 1], ['RX', 'RX', 'RX'])
```

Comment: Thanks for solution,but i tried a different solution ,as I wanted to using spark.Thanks for your effort!.

Comment: @Abid that solution was for spark :)